# What is the best way to handle JComponents based on Java Data Types?

Tags: java, swing, dynamic, jcomponent

I have a program which creates a gui to trigger APIs, and using Reflect im reading the necessary parameters of the API and want to create a user input so that the user can prepare the API before execution.

For example:

`void getAccountInfo(String name, int id, long customer_id, double balnce, boolean isActive)`

What I'm trying to figure out is what is the best way to dynamically display the JComponent inputs based on the datatypes of the API parameters.

I created the following switch statment which is basically reading the datatype of each variable and creates a different JComponent, but I found out that this will cause some issues:

```
switch(entry.getValue().getSimpleName()){
    case "int":
        //SpinnerModel intSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
        inputComponent = new JSpinner();
        break;
    case "long":
        //SpinnerModel longSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0, Long.MIN_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE, 1);
        inputComponent = new JSpinner();
        break;
    case "double":
        //SpinnerModel doubleSpinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0.00, -1.0e100, 1.0e100, 0.01);
        inputComponent = new JSpinner();
        break;
    case "boolean":
        inputComponent = new JComboBox<String>(new String[] { null, "true", "false" });
        break;
    case "String":
        inputComponent = new JTextField();
        break;
}
```

For now this works great but it will cause issues in the future:

1. In case of `char` I cannot add a JTextField because the user might pass more than 1 character
2. In case of numeric values I cannot use a JSpinner because if `int` then I should not allow decimals, if `float` or `double` I should not allow more than 2 decimals. I tried using `SpinnerModel` but seems like is not working properly.

Is there an alternative approach to what I'm trying to achieve here or should I just focus on fixing the existing code! For this I'm only using `java.swing` and `java.awt`

---

Based on Comments by Abra
[image]

Comment: I suggest a [JTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) with three columns: _name_ , _type_ and _value_ where _name_ is the name of the field or method parameter, _type_ is its type, e.g. `char`, `int`, etc and _value_ is the value to assign. You can make the _value_ column editable and use different components as editors. Note that you can create an appropriate model for [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) [Continued in next comment.]

Comment: You can use a [DocumentFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) for `JTextField` or use a [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html).

Comment: I have added a screenshot from my gui. Using a JTable will not help in in the validations, but only how things are displayed.
For your second comment, are these two libraries used on all JComponents or just JTextField?

Comment: _Using a JTable will not help in in the validations_ Of-course it will. _are these two libraries used on all JComponents_ Did you read the links I posted in my other comments?

Comment: *I tried using SpinnerModel but seems like is not working properly.* - post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: *Using a JTable will not help in in the validations* - a JTable supports some default editors. You can also customize editors. See: [Using an Editor to Validate User Entered Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#validtext)